# how loop video with javascript?

Tags: javascript, video, infinite-loop

i have some videos source. I want to play it again when the last video is over. I tried this code below,but after the last ended it wont start from the beginning.

Here's my code below

**HTML**

```
<video id="myVideo" width="800" height="600" controls>
 Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
  <script>
  var videoSource = new Array();
  videoSource[0]='video/adsfsaf.mp4';
  videoSource[1]='video/2.mp4';
  videoSource[2]='video/1.mp4';
  var videoCount = videoSource.length;

  document.getElementById("myVideo").setAttribute("src",videoSource[0]);
  function videoPlay(videoNum)
  {
  document.getElementById("myVideo").setAttribute("src",videoSource[videoNum]);
  document.getElementById("myVideo").load();
  document.getElementById("myVideo").play();
  }
  function videoBegin(videoNum)
  {
  document.getElementById("myVideo").setAttribute("src",videoSource[0]);
  document.getElementById("myVideo").load();
  document.getElementById("myVideo").play();
  }
  i = 0;
  document.getElementById('myVideo').addEventListener('ended',myHandler,false);
  function myHandler() {
    i++;
    if(i == (videoCount-1)){
      // alert(i);
    videoPlay(i);
    }
    else{
    videoPlay(i);
    }
  }
  </script
```

**I found the solution.**

```
  function myHandler() {
    i++;
    if(i >= videoCount) i =0;
    videoPlay(i);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use the "loop" attribute of the "video" element ?

[W3School loop](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_video_loop.asp)

Comment: actually already did,  i forgot to explain more. the video only loop for the first video